# Previous package in R causing errors

Tags: packages, r

Long ago I used a package called gdalUtils.

I don't need it currently and it isn't installed on my current version's library, but its absence is causing errors when I try to install other packages:

```
Error in loadNamespace(x) : there is no package called ‘gdalUtils’
Calls: loadNamespace -> withRestarts -> withOneRestart -> doWithOneRestart
Execution halted
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘pkgbuild’ had non-zero exit status
Error in loadNamespace(x) : there is no package called ‘gdalUtils’
Calls: loadNamespace -> withRestarts -> withOneRestart -> doWithOneRestart
Execution halted
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘testthat’ had non-zero exit status
```

I can't install it now:

```
> install.packages("gdalUtils")
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘gdalUtils’ is not available for this version of R
```

And I can't remove it:

```
Removing package from ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Error in remove.packages : there is no package called ‘gdalUtils’
```

I tried purging the cache with package renv:

```
> purge( "gdalUtils" )
* The requested package is not installed in the cache -- nothing to do.

> 
Restarting R session...

Error in loadNamespace(x) : there is no package called ‘gdalUtils’
```

How can I make R forget that I ever had such a package?

Comment: Did you try purging the cache https://rstudio.github.io/renv/reference/purge.html?

Comment: Thank you, no, I had not, but it didn't work.  Edited question with the attempt.

Comment: That's invalid command that  you used. Without quotes it's an object. You need to turn it into a string as in examples shown in the link above.

Comment: Thanks for that correction @Destroy666.  I edited the question with the correct command.  Still no joy.

Comment: One more thing to try - Ctrl + Shift + F10 (session restart)

Comment: Thanks, that doesn't work on my setup, Shift-Command-0 does. I restarted the session numerous times, and each time get the error "Restarting R session...
Error in loadNamespace(x) : there is no package called ‘gdalUtils’".

Answer (score 1):

[gdalUtils](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gdalUtils) was removed from CRAN.

There is a read-only mirror of the CRAN R package repository.

`gdalUtils` is no longer in CRAN because it hasn't been maintained in at least a couple of years but you can try to install it from the GitHub repository.

You can try:

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools:::install_github("gearslaboratory/gdalUtils")
```

Please note - using this you'll ride a dead horse. You should think about a clean new R setup.